# Building executable jar with maven cannot include Oracle JDBC driver

Tags: maven, executable-jar, oracle12c

I need to copy Oracle JDBC Driver located in the classpath.

Command : `mvn clean package`

I tried also :

`mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc.jar -DgeneratePom=true`

But always I get the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle JDBC drivers are to be downloaded either from [OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) and installed or you can download them from Oracle maven repository using the instructions in the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides).